# During run of webscraping I get a timeout

Tags: python, web-scraping

Running file and get timeout after about 75-100 urls scraped.

I've tried putting a delay in and getting same result, not sure what else to try. Any input would be appreciated.

```
    urls = [line.strip() for line in inf]

    for url in urls:
        sourceCode = requests.get(url)
        plainText = sourceCode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")
        irock = soup.find_all('div', class_="card-img-container")

        for img in irock:
            imageElement = img.find("img")
            bingo = imageElement.get("data-src")
            imgName = imageElement.get("title")
            fullName = str(imgName) + ".jpg"
            r = urllib.request.urlretrieve(bingo, fullName)

        print(url)

    print("Done")
```

Comment: Please share code.

Comment: with open('list.txt') as inf:
    urls = (line.strip() for line in inf)
    for url in urls:
        sourceCode = requests.get(url)
        plainText = sourceCode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")

        irock = (soup.find_all('div', class_="card-img-container"))

        for img in irock:
            imageElement = img.find("img")
            bingo = imageElement.get("data-src")

Comment: for title in irock:
                imgName = imageElement.get("title")

                fullName = str(imgName) + ".jpg"

                urllib.request.urlretrieve(bingo, fullName)

        sleep(randint(1, 3))

Comment: Edit your question to include your code.

Comment: edited but wont let me have both the code and the error

Comment: As before... you don't need innermost loop and you do need to do something with return from request. We do need to see the error however. Have you verified value of url when fails?

Comment: it just goes to a certain amount like i said 75-100 and timesout

Comment: running now with the changes you recommended in the other question and no delay to see what happens. Will post here results when I find out. Thank you.

Comment: So far gone through url 752 to 877 no hangups. So having the loop inside a loop was causing some kind of memory leak or something? Then eventually timing out?